# Equivalent of from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops import arg_scope in tf2.0?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm looking for the equivalent of from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops import arg_scope and add_arg_scope since the contrib module has been eliminated in tf 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

From tensorflow [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate):

Remove `arg_scopes`, all args need to be explicit there.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `arg_scope` is now a part of `tf_slim` library.

```
from tf_slim import arg_scope
```